# Nav2 - Pose estimation

Tags: ros2, localization, nav2

my problem is that when I give 2D pose estimation, to estimate the robot pose of the real robot, the robot, the lidar scan and the local costmap will start to move left and right, basically, the map->odom transformation is changing continuously. Is this due to the local localization or this is due to the AMCL?
Thanks.

Example of the behaviour:
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS + ROS2 Humble + Nav2

Links: [nav2_params.yaml](https://github.com/mattiadutto/scout-navigation/blob/main/config/nav2_params.yaml), [ekf_localization_with_gps.yaml](https://github.com/mattiadutto/scout-navigation/blob/main/config/ekf_localization_with_gps.yaml), [nav2.launch.py](https://github.com/mattiadutto/scout-navigation/blob/main/launch/nav2.launch.py).